# Check whether two conjugate subgroups are still conjugate in some subgroup

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Given a group $G$ and $K<G$. Let $H_1,H_2$ be subgroups in $G$ satisfying:

\begin{align}
  &H_1\triangleleft K;\\
  &H_2\triangleleft K;\\
  &H_1\sim_G H_2.\quad\mbox{(They are conjugate to each other in $G$)}
\end{align}

Is it true that

\begin{align}
  H_1\sim_{N_G(K)}H_2,
\end{align}

where $N_G(K)$ denotes the normalizer of $K$ in $G$? Or is there a counterexample?
Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G=S_6$, $H_1=\langle (1,2,3) \rangle$, $H_2=\langle (4,5,6) \rangle$, $K = \langle (1,2,3),(4,5,6),(4,5) \rangle \cong C_3 \times S_3$.

Comment: BTW, in case you have not seen, there is now a chatroom (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19567/finite-group-theory) for finite group theory in case you are interested (sorry for the somewhat off-topic comment).

Comment: It would be interesting to explain how this was conceived. =)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Is your comment referring to my answer or to Tobias Kildetoft's comment?

Comment: @DerekHolt Your answer.

Comment: Well I knew the answer was going to be no (since there is no reason I could think of why it should be true), so it was just a matter of thinking of an example. I decided I would look for a subgroup $H_1 \times H_2$ of a group $G$ with $H_1$ and $H_2$ conjugate in $G$, and then try and embed $H_2$ normally in a bigger group $K_2$ that still commuted with $H_1$. Then $H_1$ and $H_2$ would be normal in $K=H_1 \times K_2$ but might not be conjugate in the normaliser of $K$, because we have distorted one of the two similar looking subgroups.

Comment: Incidentally, in this example, you could take $G$ to be the subgroup $\langle (1,2,3), (1,2), (4,5,6), (4,5), (1,4)(2,5)(3,6) \rangle$ of $S_6$, which is isomorphic to the wreath product $S_3 \wr C_2$ and has order $72$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, I was trying to find all the conjugacy classes of subgroups in the direct product of two groups, and this question is what I encountered in the procedure.